# Consecutive rising sequence of largest prime factors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the function $f(n)$ defined on the natural integers which returns the largest prime factor of $n$, and is $0$ for $1$. For example, $f(9)=3$,$f(15)=5$.

A beautiful riddle says that there are infinitely many $n$ so that $f(n)<f(n+1)<f(n+2)$.

I have 2 questions:

1.Given $k$, are there infinitely many $n$ so that $f(n)<f(n+1)...<f(n+k)$?

2.How often is $f(n)<f(n+1)$?

Proof of the riddle:

Lemma 1, if $f(a)<c, f(b)<c$, then $f(ab)<c$.

For any odd prime $q$ we find such different $n$, as there are infinitely many different odd primes we're done.

Choose an odd prime $q$, try $n+1=q$. Obviously $f(n)<f(n+1)$.

If $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ we're done. Otherwise, choose $n+1$=$q^2$. Now $f(n)=f(q^2-1)=f((q−1)(q+1))$, so by lemma 1, by setting $a=q-1$, $b=q+1$, $c=q$  we get $f(n)<f(n+1)$. Again if $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ we're done, otherwise choose $n+1=q^4$ and keep going like that. Assume by contradiction this goes on forever, then $q=f(q^{2^k})>f(q^{2^k}+1)$ for all $k$, but $gcd(q^{2^k}+1,q^{2^m}+1) = 1$ for all different $m,n$, and so eventually they contain primes larger than $q$, contradiction.

Comment: what is the argument for showing $f(n)<f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ infinitely often ? And I'd say the asymptotic density of $1_{f(n)<f(n+1)}$ is $1/2$

Comment: @user1952009
Lemma, if $f(a)<c$,$f(b)<c$, then $f(ab)<c$
For any odd prime $q$ we find such $n$.
Choose a prime $q$, try $n+1$=$q$. Obviously $f(n)<f(n+1)$. If $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ we're done. Otherwise, choose $n+1$=$q^2$. Now $f(n)=f(q-1)f(q+1)$, so by lemma 1 and because our last guess for $n$ failed we get $f(n)<f(n+1)$. Again if $f(n+1)<f(n+2)$ works we're done, other wise choose $n+1=q^4$ and keep going like that.

Assume by contradiction this goes on forever, then $ q=f(q^2^k)>f(q^2^k+1) $ for all $k$, but $(q^2^k+1,q^2^m+1) = 1$ for all different $m,n$, and so eventually they...

Comment: @user1952009 must contain primes larger than q, a contradiction.

Comment: @user1952009 I'll add it, thanks.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/261640/consecutive-rising-sequence-of-largest-prime-factors